# MySQL: clone rows inside one table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have one table with the next content

```
stat_id|stat_type|stat_value
1      |likes    |100
1      |reposts  |150
```

Is it possible to clone these rows for another `stat_id`'s in one query?

It's important that we want copies for several new `stat_id`.

Comment: @Vatev oh, thanks! I didn't find this question when I was searching

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT ... SELECT`

```
insert into your_table (c1, c2, ...)
select c1, c2, ...
from your_table
where id = 1
```

Comment: Hm. Stop. But how I can make clones with several different ids? I have rows for `stat_id` - 1. And I want to create clones for bulk of new ids.

Comment: I mean. I can do something likes this: `insert into stats (stat_id, stat_type, stat_value) select 2, stat_type, stat_week from .....` But I want to do clones for more than one new ids.